# How can we ignore uncaught exceptions in current function when debugging?

Tags: exception, debugging, ironpython

Here's an oddity I ran into when running some code.  I was playing with old python assignments I've done in school - embedding them in C# programs, running them with IronPython, etc.

Embedding the code worked as I would expect it, same when running in IronPython interactive.  I then ran it in a new IronPython project and found some awkward behavior.  Running the code *without* debugging gave normal behavior.  Running *with* debugging started giving off unhandled exception errors (which turned out to be just warnings after looking in to it, more on that later).

It was a head scratcher for me.  Stepping through the code, I found that everything was happening as I should have expected.  However at certain points, it would stop and would show the unhandled exception window pointing at seemingly random parts of the code.  In an attempt at finding out what was wrong, I came up with this code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

def raiser():
    print('raising an exception')
    raise Exception() # unreported exception here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        raiser()
    except Exception: # but is handled here
        print('caught it')
    #raiser() # ignoring exceptions would leave this unreported
```

Now here it should be pretty obvious what happens here.  Running it without debugging runs normally.  Running it with debugging, it stops, showing that there was an unhandled exception.  It *is* handled, just not in the scope of the `raiser()` function.  That's when I realized that this was a *warning*... 2 hours on a goose chase going crazy over such a simple thing.

- Can this warning be disabled or suppressed somehow?

Now this kind of warning I might expect for a beginner who needs all the help they can get, but I am far from beginner on this and don't care that there's the exception isn't handled in the current function scope, just that it is handled *somewhere* in my code.  I can't find any references to this online or any settings in Visual Studio.

- Is there some new requirement to have to declare that exceptions will be raised for the debugger?
  (akin to Java's checked exceptions)
- Would this be a candidate for a bug report?

This is on IronPython 2.7 Stable (which I just installed hours ago) running off of Visual Studio 2010 Pro.  I don't recall if this was ever an issue in prior versions, I've never tried the code via the debugger then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an odd interaction between the .NET debugger and how IronPython exceptions are raised. A workaround is to go into the "Debug -> Exceptions..." window, click "Add...", and add `IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.PythonException` as a CLR exception. Then, clear the "User-unhandled" checkbox, which will tell the debugger to ignore uncaught Python exceptions.

You could also try running under the [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) instead and see if it has different behaviour. Otherwise, please file a bug so that we at least know about it.

Comment: That did it. I didn't expect to have to add the exception. I thought the installer would have done this or at least it would be listed.  Though now the problem is that any legitimately uncaught exceptions won't be reported by the debugger.

Comment: I'm also running into this, and I've crossposted that report into the pytools codeplex at http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/358 in hopes of attracting more attention to this issue.

Comment: @Aphex: Thanks for the follow ups you've been doing on this issue.  Hopefully it will help speed up the process of fixing the problem.

Comment: I'm pleased to report that if run using IronPython 2.7 + PTVS 1.0 with the debug launch mode set to `Standard Python Launcher`, the exceptions are caught and reported as expected (and all debugging functions are functional again).  However reverting to the `IronPython launcher` will have the usual problems listed here.  (ping @Aphex)

Comment: Right, I was aware of that. Given that I develop in IronPython, though, I must use the Ironpython launcher, which as you mentioned, still exhibits this issue. I still hold out some hope that this will be fixed in the next IronPython release (as mentioned by Dino Viehland, this is an IPy issue, not a PTVS issue)